# Is there a way to package cygwin packages installation

Tags: windows, cygwin, installation-package

Each time I have to reinstall my computer or new incomers arrive in our team, we install cygwin, and each time, we forget to install a package. 
We can write somewhere useful packages, (i even just did it ^^).

But is there a way, to package cygwin packages, for example a texte file with all useful cygwin packages, that we give as argument setup.exe, or something like that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be possible by using [the --packages (-P) parameter](http://www.cygwin.com/faq/faq.setup.html#faq.setup.cli) for the Cygwin Setup.exe. A nice sample batch script can be found [here](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2011-09/msg00097.html):

```
setup.exe ^
--no-shortcuts ^
--quiet-mode ^
--disable-buggy-antivirus ^
--packages ^
aria2,^
atool,^
autoconf,^
automake,^
autossh,^
[...]
```

Of course compiling a list of your favorite packages would still be needed, which can be done using [cygcheck -c](http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-utils.html).

Comment: Great ! thx, i will try this asap.